# What's the difference between Start time and Starting time?

Tags: word-difference

what is the difference between start time and starting time?

If I am talking about work start time at a job site, can I say starting time is 7 in the morning?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning, so either would work in your sentence. There's not a big difference in popularity either, although "start time" looks to be more popular.

---

You can see evidence for this in either [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=start+time%2C+starting+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstart%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstarting%20time%3B%2Cc0) or the BYU corpora (although to use the latter you need to create a free account). For the BYU corpora I checked [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and [BNC](https://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/). I searched specifically for `START time`, which matches any form of "start". Do note that "start time" seems to be overrepresented because there are one or two sources that use the expression a lot, with each instance being reported as its own hit.